# How to fold edges?

Tags: edges

Iam learning blender and trying to recreate this model. As you can see, my model has sharp edges and because of it, the outfit look paper thin. The other guy's model on other hand, his edges look thick and his outfit look really good. I took a close look and the guy was folding his edge, to make it look thick. How did he do that, guys?
[image]

Comment: You could use a Solidify modifier but if you ever apply it it will make twice the number of faces. Or just keep the thickness where it is visible. Also, before working with high-poly mesh, work on a low-poly, it will make the things much easier, at the end you can apply a Subdivision Surface modifier if it's really necessary (but always keep a copy of the original somewhere)

Comment: Much obliged it moonboots!

Answer (score 2):

Try a *Solidify* modifier.

In the *Properties* panel, *Modifiers* tab (wrench icon) click the *Add Modifier* button.

Choose *Solidify*.

You can adjust the *Thickness* value to change the thickness.